# React-redux: I want use .map() to return two <tr> in <tbody> ,but i don't know how to do that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i want to click a button to add two tr tags in a tbody tags 
and click edit button to hide  below .but i just can finish a row and i don't know what to  do next

```
<tbody>
{
functions.map((fun, index) => {

    return <tr key={index}>
        <td>
            <Input type="text" placeholder="n" value={fun.n}
                    onChange={(e) => setValueN(index, e.target.value)}/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <Input type="text" placeholder="p" value={fun.p}
                    onChange={(e) => setValueP(index, e.target.value)}/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <Icon name="question"></Icon>
            <Button icon={fun.onShow ? "delete" : "edit"} onClick={() => edit(index)}>
                {fun.onShow ? "delete" : "edit"}
            </Button>
            <Button icon="remove" onClick={() => delete(index)}>
                delete
            </Button>
        </td>
    </tr>
})
```

}

Comment: if you increment values in functions then it will automatically add new row

Comment: thank you i had finished it !